# Trying to get HTML HREF SMS link working in jasonette for android

Tags: android, sms, href, jasonette

I have an SMS href link that works great in the mobile browser but when deployed to android using jasonette I get ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME. Is there a simple fix for this or is it even possible?

```
<a href="sms://+15558675309">Text</a>
```

Here is my json file-

```
{
"$jason": {
    "head": {
        "title": "Web Container Agent"

    },
    "body": {
        "background": {
            "type": "html",
            "url": "www.mysite.com/test.php",
            "id": "app",
            "action": {
               "type": "$default"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very new to this but i also had the same sort of problem, it was fixed by setting the correct view.

"view": "app"

Something like this works

```
{ "type": "label", 
        "text": "text message", 
        "href": {
          "url": "sms://+87687687688678",
         "view": "app"
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the view in the json file under action? I updated the question to show my json file